# Can you get polygon coordinates from a ggplot2::geom_density_2d_filled plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to get the coordinates of the polygons created from using geom_density_2d_filled?

Example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble (x = sample(1:100, 50, rep = TRUE),
              y = sample(1:100, 50, rep = TRUE))

g <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x=x,y=y),
                         bins=10)
```

Can I get an area definition of one or more of the shapes created? Would be happy with a roughly drawn polygon. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get the (x, y) coordinates of the contour lines, you can extract using `ggplot_build` and looking at the `data` element.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ggbld <- ggplot_build(g)

gdata <- ggbld$data[[1]]
head(gdata)
```

**Output**

```
       fill                level         x        y piece  group subgroup    level_low
1 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05] 10.717172 8.185262     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
2 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05]  9.787879 8.639536     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
3 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05]  9.475167 8.797980     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
4 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05]  8.858586 9.107321     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
5 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05]  7.929293 9.597925     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
6 #440154FF (1.56e-05, 3.11e-05]  7.639536 9.757576     1 -1-002        1 1.555556e-05
    level_high    level_mid nlevel  n PANEL colour size linetype alpha
1 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
2 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
3 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
4 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
5 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
6 3.111111e-05 2.333333e-05    0.2 50     1     NA  0.5        1    NA
```

Then you can plot by level to demonstrate:

```
gdata %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x, y, color = level))
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Just a note that the levels map in a donut shape to exclude higher levels (bins). Using subgroups I was able to grab each shape to include the higher levels like this: gdata %>% filter(piece == 4, subgroup == 2). This would map one shape.